# Barplot display in R.shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

i have developed a code to display bar data according to reaction buttons how ever i would like to to know exact number if i move the cursor on the bar of display it next to it

the code

```
library("shiny")
data = data.matrix(MY_data[1:4])
ui=fluidPage(    

  # Give the page a title
  titlePanel("Age ranges according to program"),

  # Generate a row with a sidebar
  sidebarLayout(      

    # Define the sidebar with one input
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton(inputId = "MBA", label = "MBA"),
      actionButton(inputId = "MSLOD", label = "MSLOD"),
      actionButton(inputId = "MSQBE", label = "MSQBE")



    ),

    # Create a spot for the barplot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("hist")  
    )

  )
)




server <- function(input, output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(data = data[1,1:4])

  observeEvent(input$MBA, { rv$data <- data[1,1:4] })
  observeEvent(input$MSLOD, { rv$data <- data[2,1:4] })
  observeEvent(input$MSQBE, { rv$data <- data[3,1:4] })

  output$hist <- renderPlot({ 

    barplot(rv$data, 
            main=input$radio,
            ylab="Number employees",
            xlab="Ages Range",col=rainbow(4))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and my data look like

```
a   b   c  d
5   133 258 106
4   59  60  28
1   34  64  28
```

as matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our project we found this feature was already implemented in plotly:

https://plot.ly/r/shiny-tutorial/

I haven't used plotly for a while, but I believe for your app you would change `plotOutput` to `plotlyOutput` in your UI, and similarly there's `renderPlotly` function in the server side.

Plotly is a little different that standard R plots, but it supports much better interactivity out of the box, so I would recommend it if you plan on making interactive plots.